# Mobile money input, easiest method

Tags: forms, input-fields, money

For a monetary input, I would have liked to use the `input[type=tel]`, but sadly the decimal/period character is missing from most telephone keyboards on mobile devices.

This is a payment amount that a user chooses, so it can be any dollar value along with any decimal value between **.00 - .99**

For now, I'm using the `input[type=number]`, but I feel there must a more user-friendly input, since on mobile devices, we try to prevent as much typing (via the standard keyboard as possible).

I'd thought about using 2 selects, one for the whole number dollar amount and the other for the decimal portion, although that may be difficult if you have to scroll through hundreds of numbers.

Comment: The *"try to avoid typing on mobile"* rule-of-thumb is useful general guidance, but should not be **over applied**. If one spends effort inventing some UI that is uncomfortably novel, slower or more inaccurate than typing, that would not make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lot of budgetary apps on iOS that use the telephone keyboard use the convention of displaying the input preformatted with a currency sign at the beginning and the decimal/period number built in:

[image]

As the user presses numbers, they display preformatted. No need for the user to add the decimal/point themselves. For example, I pressed the numbers 1, 2, 3, and 4, and this is what the app displayed:

[image]

Comment: Compared to everything else I've tried, this approach of taking in numbers in reverse order works the **best**! ESPECIALLY considering that iOS' `input[type=num]` keyboard has no decimals. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Consider native mobile controls**

The number input will show a number pad with decimal. It is probably best to keep it straight-forward and provide a single number input with help text with an example input. You can always validate with regex to check for decimal, etc. Append a **$** for USD or other if localization is a concern.

Using `input[type=tel]` for a money would loose semantic meaning, a less optimal solution.

Pardon the old phone but here's an example of a simple approach. The user simply types it in, less clicks less UI.

Ultimately you'll want to test a couple of different designs with users to validate assumptions.

[Phone http://gyroscopestudios.com/stackexchange/phone-number.png](http://gyroscopestudios.com/stackexchange/phone-number.png)

Comment: That's what I'm using right now, I was looking for a better approach.

Comment: Even if there was a magical article out there titled 'best approach for Feng' the only way to know is involving your users. Do some Think-Aloud user testing with ~5 people. This will give you *your* best approach. It is the only way to validate a guess.

Comment: @Ken For me "test with users" or "it depends" is a kind of none-answer. There are best practises out there and it's sound to ask for it.

Comment: @FrankL you are suggesting that best practices are a replacement for user-driven design? Best practices are inherently flawed because they are designed to suit most situations pretty well. While it can be a good starting point, it is not a replacement for real user centered design work.

Comment: @Ken Sure. Feng was asking for a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Take the typepad an ATM uses (context of money is kept and buttons are big). Note that ATM and phone are using same layout ;)

Add a point and a delete button on it.

And an okay/ done button.

That's it.

Test with users which order of typing numbers in the field is prefered: first cents and then dollars or first dollars then cents. This can be culturally different.
I did a mobile payment app in Germany.